# Show progress bar for long operation?

Tags: tramp, files, compression

Linux Mint 20.2

Emacs 27.2

When I do some long operation not show progress bar.

Is it possible to show progress bar in this situation?

Examples of long operations:

- Copy many files
- Copy big files
- Compress/Uncompress archive
- Connect by Tramp to remote host
- etc.

Comment: Some of these things (maybe most) are slow because of work being done outside of Emacs. Certainly, connecting to a remote host with Tramp is delayed by the response of that host, and any delays in the network itself. I'm not sure what information would be available to Emacs to generate a progress bar for such things

Comment: @Tyler Is it possible in dired  to show how many files was copeid/compress? Smt like 1/10, 2/10, 3/10 ... 10/10